# Remove newline characters from Cassandra query results

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I am using the python Cassandra driver to query a database.
This is the code that I ran:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import dict_factory

ips = [...]
cluster = Cluster(ips)
session = cluster.connect()
session.row_factory = dict_factory
session.set_keyspace("mykeyspace")
response = session.execute("SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE mykey = 'xyz';")
```

In the output, I get weird 'n's in front of words, where newline characters used to be.

Example:

"Over the wintry **n**forest, winds howl in  rage **n**with no leaves to blow."

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: try *response = session.execute("SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE mykey = 'xyz';").rstrip('\n')*

Comment: does not work, because **response** is of type <class 'cassandra.cluster.ResultSet'> and I  tried
`for line in response:
    line['mycolumn'].strip('\n')`
that did not wor either

Comment: can you include your schema and how they were inserted?

Comment: @Chris Lohfink I don't have that info. Is there a way I can get that using the python driver?

Comment: how did you put the data into cassandra? Issue is more likely there, C* doesnt do anything to the data, just store and return it.

Comment: Can you do a `":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in line['mycolumn'])` so we can check that it is a \n?

Comment: so this is the string **die nPolitik** and this is the output **64:69:65:20:6e:50:6f:6c:69:74:69:6b**

Comment: so thats literally "n" that was inserted, not \n. Probably whatever you were using to insert the data was escaping it first and removed the \, not rendering as the new line char.

Comment: I tried it with the java driver, and in the output one can clearly see the correct result with "\n". So I guess the problem is with the python driver. Is there a way to tell the python driver not to escape/unescape items when it is getting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your data ingestion, or whatever is consuming `response` not in the drivers reading. It is the `n` in stored your database, not the `\n` char. The python driver does not escape or do anything from the raw bytes but convert to string: https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/9869c2a044e5dd76309026437bcda5d01acf99c7/cassandra/cqltypes.py#L693

If you insert a `\n` you get one back out:

```
session.execute('CREATE TABLE mydb (mykey text PRIMARY KEY, mycolumn text);')
session.execute("INSERT INTO mydb (mykey, mycolumn) VALUES ('xyz', 'a\nb');")
response = session.execute("SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE mykey = 'xyz';")
for line in response:
   print line['mycolumn']
```

correctly outputs:

```
a
b
```

Is there something taking `response` and escaping it afterwards?

Comment: You are right, we looked into the database and found the issue there. Thanks for your help.